# Ascending and descending array

Tags: arrays, algorithm

I have to build an array like this :

```
7 2 5 2 4 3 8
```

and check if the even numbers are in an ascending order AND the odd numbers are in a descending order...if this is true it returns 1 else it returns 0

for the array i've given the value returned is 1
I honestly have no idea how to do this..any ideas??

Comment: what did you try ? besides you question looks more like an algorithmic question than a specific c++ question

Comment: I've thought about forming 2 separate arrays for even and for odd numbers in the array but I have no idea how to start

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just traverse your array keeping the maximal even value seen so far and the minimal odd value seen so far. Check that these don't decrease (resp. increase) while traversing the array.

Answer (score 0):

Use %2 to find if it is even and odd. Loop through the array twice, checking even numbers for the first time and checking odd numbers for the second. If both checks go through, return 1.

Comment: He could just do that in a single sweep.

Comment: okay but even numbers HAVE to be in an ascending order and odd numbers HAVE to be in a descending order

Answer (score 0):

initialize 2 variables asc_odd and desc_even =1 as flag variables.Iterate through the loop and check if consecutive even numbers and odd are in correct order with the use of if statement and % operator(to check odd or even.) If then are not in order change their flag variable to 0.

Answer (score 0):

```
int main()
{
int array[100];
int i,n;
int init_asc =0,init_desc = 0;
int asc_Flag = 0,desc_Flag = 0;
int asc_prev,desc_prev;
cout << "\nEnter the no Of Numbers:\t";
cin >>n;
cout <<"\nEnter the numbers :\t";
for(i=0; i < n; i++){
    cin>> array[i];
}

for( i=0; i < n; i++ )
{
    if(array[i]%2 == 0)
    {
        if(init_asc==0)
        {
            init_asc =1;
            asc_prev = array[i];
        }
        else
        {
            if(asc_prev > array[i])
                asc_Flag = 1;
            else
                asc_prev = array[i];
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if(init_desc==0)
        {
            init_desc =1;
            desc_prev = array[i];
        }
        else
        {
            if(desc_prev < array[i])
                desc_Flag = 1;
            else
                desc_prev = array[i];
        }
    }
}

if(!(asc_Flag|desc_Flag))
    cout << "\nTrue\n";
else
    cout << "\nFalse\n";
 }
```

Here is the code which will do the above operation, Ask if you need any clarification